# PIL show Image only RGB Values (Image from PlanetScope Planet Product)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have this image (which was taken from Planet Lab's PlanetScope product (not sure if that matters)). The image file is a .tif file and has 4 channels: R, G, B, and NIR. Link to original image here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g9tZar41tU3E_y5oev1Gy77hGiKB1q7L

I'm just trying to do something basic where I am trying to load the image into Pillow using Python and using Matplotlib to show the image. But, I think what's happening is that the fourth channel is being assumed to be an alpha channel so the images look a bit weird. I want to only visualize the R, G, B components. How do I do this?

I currently have something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image 

img = Image.open(image_file)
plt.imshow(img)

# Subsetting the array
img_arr = np.array(img)

# Plotting only the first 3 channels
plt.imshow(img_arr[:, :, 0:3])

# After asking PIL to drop NIR Channel
img_rgb = Image.open(image_files).convert('RGB')
plt.imshow(img_rgb)
```

In both cases, the images look like it's not really plotting RGB

[image]

EDIT: I did `img = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')` and the image looks roughly the same?

[image: After asking Pillow to convert to RGB]

Comment: Try asking PIL to drop the NIR channel on open `img = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')`

Comment: Or share a link to your image... Dropbox, Google Drive....

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell just added a link to the image in the original post.

Comment: That rendition looks like what's in the image. Why do you think it is wrong? How do you expect it to look?